# How to upload Images to Sky Drive in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

How i can upload my images to skydrive. I tried with hotmail apis but failed. Does windows phone mango support this feature. Please help me to find a soln for this issue.

regards,
  Stephan

Comment: You mean programmically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nikovrdoljak’s mentioned a method for backup isolated storage data to sky drive. Try this method. I don't know whether it will solve ur issue or not but try it.
[link]
http://nikovrdoljak.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/backup-your-windows-phone-isolated-storage-data-to-skydrive-using-live-connect-api/

Answer (score 1):

Please visit following link i am sure that it will help you...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826531.aspx#uploading_files